# Display relative and absolute line numbers simultaneously in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there any way to display *both* **relative** and **absolute** line numbers simultaneously in Vim? Either side-by-side, or some other interesting presentation are fine.

Comment: Unimpaired.vim has a toggle mapping `yor` which is convenient to see absolute numbers for a quick second, and come back to hybrid setting. https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/4afbe5ebf32ad85341b4c02b0e1d8ca96a64c561/doc/unimpaired.txt

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use [RltvNmbr.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2351) to display the relative numbers, and use Vim to display the absolute ones:

[image]

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL  I have installed that plug-in, But need it to display in the starting of the vim itself. What should i enter in the `.vimrc` file?

Comment: enable this plugin really slow the entire vim e.g. when changing the lines by j/k..

Comment: even when jumping directly to the line, the refresh rate is brutish for every jump

Comment: I installed this plugin.  It slows down vim whenever I move up/down a line (k/j) and it doesn't seem to work when opening and dealing with buffers.  Are there any fixes for those issues?

Comment: you can enable this plugin in `.vimrc` with: `call RltvNmbr#RltvNmbrCtrl(1) `

Comment: @PathSeeker I am using nvim but this command not worked

Comment: The owner of this plugin says it"s very heavy. https://nanasi.jp/articles/vim/rltvnmbr_vim.html

Answer (score 21):

Vim 7.4 (Patch [7.3.787](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/vMX1-KYOB9M)) will show the absolute line number instead of "0", when both "relativenumber" and "number" are set.

From `:h relativenumber`, 7.3

> When setting this option, 'number' is reset.

From `:h relativenumber`, 7.4

> The number in front of the cursor line also depends on the value of
>   'number', see |number_relativenumber| for all combinations of the two
>   options.

Answer (score 12):

Reasonably speaking, you can't. Line numbering is one-per-buffer, controlled solely by the `'number'` option.

One crazy notion I tried: `:vertical diffsplit` plus `:setlocal relativenumber`. This gets two copies of the buffer next to one another, linked in scroll position because they're in diff mode. However, it really doesn't work properly. The relative numbers aren't updated successfully (on 7.3.154, bug potentially fixed later, but I doubt it—it's scarcely worth it), and even if they did, you'd be stuck with a great eyesore and harder management and navigation.

You could do it with a plugin writing to a special buffer which you would keep on the left, but the implementation would be ugly, and it would still make navigation hard (because it's another buffer). I for one am certainly not going to spend time writing such a plugin, though I must confess I'd like to show both forms of line numbering.

Comment: Ah, you've thought about it desperately as I have. :)

Comment: @mt3 and you may be interested to return to thia Q&A and see that a plugin solution has been posted as an answer

Comment: OK, I've deselected this one as accepted, and selected the actual plugin.

Answer (score 12):

Many years later and this feature is now part of Vim and known as hybrid numbers.

You can turn this feature on by entering:

```
:set number relativenumber
```

No speed penalty either. As far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7):

Combining **plnx** and **Macario** answers with vim 7.4.

```
autocmd WinEnter,FocusGained * :setlocal number relativenumber
autocmd WinLeave,FocusLost   * :setlocal number norelativenumber
```

This displays Relative Numbering (with current line in Absolute) in the focused window, and Absolute in the non-focused window.

Comment: For me this did not trigger on newly opened files (from the command line or from ctrl-p), so I changed `autocmd WinEnter,FocusGained` to `autocmd BufReadPre,FileReadPre,winenter,focusgained`

Comment: Which version of `vim` are you using? Works for me with `8.1.1467` in both `vim` and `gvim` on Void Linux. (`vim test` or `gvim test`, switch to INSERT mode, type a few lines, switch back to NORMAL mode, navigate up and down.)

Comment: neovim@head. It worked for me when entering and exiting insert mode but did not work when opening a new file

Comment: must be a delta with neovim.  (I only use (g)vim).  Maybe open a bug report?

Answer (score 3):

This are my mappings related to relative and absolute line numbers
 toggles between relative and absolute.

Entering a window sets the window to relative numbers, while leaving it set it to absolute.
Then if you do a vertical split of the window you would se the same buffer with relative and absoulte numbers.

```
" setglobal relativenumber
autocmd WinEnter * :setlocal relativenumber
autocmd WinLeave,FocusLost * :setlocal number
autocmd InsertEnter * :setlocal number
autocmd InsertLeave * :setlocal relativenumber

function! g:ToggleNuMode()
  if(&relativenumber == 1)
    set number
  else
    set relativenumber
  endif
endfunc

map <C-l> :call g:ToggleNuMode()<CR>
```